# why getting response as download option in below script running

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, iframe

while submitting below form  I receives response as download not in my intended field. am i doing something wrong here?

```
function sendFile(formimg,editor,welEditable) {

        alert("inside send");

        var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');

        $("body").append(iframe);
        alert("1");

        $('#' + formimg).attr("action", "UploadServlet");
        $('#' + formimg).attr("method", "post");
        $('#' + formimg).attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        $('#' + formimg).attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
        $('#' + formimg).attr("target", "postiframe");

        $('#' + formimg).submit();

        alert("2");
        $("#postiframe").load(function () {
            iframeContents = $("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            return iframeContent;
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You are appending jquery object and not an element

Comment: @niko um, that is valid.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the JavaScript code, has to do with how the server is returning the data. Is there a reason you are just not using `$.post()`. Also your use of $('#' + formimg) over and over again is bad. You have the object in the variable `iframe` and attr() can accept an object.

Comment: @epascarello I do not want my page to be refreshed thas why going for iframe

Comment: And how would an Ajax call refresh the page?

Comment: @epascarello $.post can't post a file. here I want to post a file. also you can consider me novice in javascript and jquery :-)